# SQL Contar ROWS

Tags: sql

Boas!

Eu tenho duas tabelas:

A: PRENUMERO (ID), DATA, ARMAZEM, TIPO

B: Autoreg (ID), PRENUMERO, PRODUTO

E eu queria ter um resultado tipo:

TotalCombustivel, TotalLoja, Misto

Em que o Combustivel é quando o produto é = 1, o Loja é >1 e o misto os dois

Se eu vir as rows todas da tabela que tenho dá isto:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora eu fiz a ligação assim:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRENUMERO])
        FROM
            [VendasPOS_Linhas]
        JOIN    [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos]
        ON    [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRENUMERO] = [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[PRENUMERO]
        WHERE
            [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[FACT_VD] like 'T' AND
            [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[DATA] > '2015-06-01 00:00:00.000' AND 
            [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[Armazem] = '454' AND
            [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRODUTO] > 1) AS QtdLoja,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRENUMERO])
        FROM
            [VendasPOS_Linhas]
        JOIN    [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos]
        ON    [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRENUMERO] = [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[PRENUMERO]
        WHERE
            [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[FACT_VD] like 'T' AND
            [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[DATA] > '2015-06-01 00:00:00.000' AND 
            [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[Armazem] = '454' AND
            [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRODUTO] = 1) AS QtdCombustivel,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[PRENUMERO]) from VendasPOS_Linhas JOIN    [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos]
        ON    [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRENUMERO] = [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[PRENUMERO] where DATA> '2015-06-01 00:00:00.000' and Armazem = '454' AND [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[FACT_VD] like 'T') AS Total
```

E o resultado dá isto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas logo aqui vejo alguns erros.

1º O Total parece que está a mais.

2º O totalComb e TotalLoja está a contar os que são do misto também

3º Na linha 11 e 12 podemos ver que tem PRENUMEROS igual mas o produto tanto é >1 como na linha de baixo = 1 e isto faz parte dos mistos. Como faço para ver se um PRENUMERO tanto tem 1 como >1 sendo que ele dá linhas diferentes. OU seja, tenho que ver quais são os duplicados e ver se o mesmo PRENUMERO tem = 1 e >1 mas não se tal é possível.

RESOLVIDO:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRENUMERO]) FROM [VendasPOS_Linhas] 
     INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRENUMERO]
            FROM
                [VendasPOS_Linhas]
            JOIN    [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos]
            ON    [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRENUMERO] = [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[PRENUMERO]
            WHERE
                [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[FACT_VD] like 'T' AND
                [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[DATA] > '2015-06-01 00:00:00.000' AND 
                [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[Armazem] = '454'
            GROUP BY [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRENUMERO]
            HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRODUTO]) = 1
        ) combustivel ON combustivel.PRENUMERO = [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRENUMERO]
        WHERE [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRODUTO] = 1
     ) AS QtdeCombustivel,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRENUMERO]) FROM [VendasPOS_Linhas] 
     INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRENUMERO]
            FROM
                [VendasPOS_Linhas]
            JOIN    [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos]
            ON    [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRENUMERO] = [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[PRENUMERO]
            WHERE
                [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[FACT_VD] like 'T' AND
                [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[DATA] > '2015-06-01 00:00:00.000' AND 
                [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[Armazem] = '454'
            GROUP BY [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRENUMERO]
            HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRODUTO]) = 1
        ) loja ON loja.PRENUMERO = [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRENUMERO]
        WHERE [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRODUTO] > 1
     ) AS QtdeLoja,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRENUMERO]) FROM [VendasPOS_Linhas] 
      INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRENUMERO]
            FROM
                [VendasPOS_Linhas]
            JOIN    [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos]
            ON    [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRENUMERO] = [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[PRENUMERO]
            WHERE
                [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[FACT_VD] like 'T' AND
                [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[DATA] > '2015-06-01 00:00:00.000' AND 
                [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[Armazem] = '454'
            GROUP BY [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRENUMERO]
            HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRODUTO]) > 1
        ) mista ON mista.PRENUMERO = [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRENUMERO]
     ) AS QtdeMista
```

Comment: Seu `total` pode estar retornando mais porque você não fez o `Join` para se certificar que só vai contar os que possuem relacionamento. Quanto ao resto está meio confuso pra mim :(

Comment: Sim faltava isso, já corrigi o total e aparece corretamente agora.
Quanto ao resto, está aqui uma imagem para ver se ajuda:

!http://i.imgur.com/toYKknJ.png

Comment: Qual o SGBD? SQL Server? MySql?

Comment: @bruno É SQLServer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tentei fazer um truque com o `HAVING COUNT`, mas não sei se vai fucionar.

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT([VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRENUMERO]) FROM [MXPETROL_AB].[dbo].[VendasPOS_Linhas] 
     INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRENUMERO]
            FROM
                [MXPETROL_AB].[dbo].[VendasPOS_Linhas]
            JOIN    [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos]
            ON    [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRENUMERO] = [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[PRENUMERO]
            WHERE
                [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[FACT_VD] like 'T' AND
                [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[DATA] > '2015-06-01 00:00:00.000' AND 
                [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[Armazem] = '454'
            GROUP BY [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRENUMERO]
            HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRODUTO]) = 1
        ) combustivel ON combustivel.PRENUMERO = [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRENUMERO]
        WHERE [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRODUTO] = 1
     ) AS QtdeCombustivel,
    (SELECT COUNT([VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRENUMERO]) FROM [MXPETROL_AB].[dbo].[VendasPOS_Linhas] 
     INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRENUMERO]
            FROM
                [MXPETROL_AB].[dbo].[VendasPOS_Linhas]
            JOIN    [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos]
            ON    [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRENUMERO] = [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[PRENUMERO]
            WHERE
                [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[FACT_VD] like 'T' AND
                [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[DATA] > '2015-06-01 00:00:00.000' AND 
                [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[Armazem] = '454'
            GROUP BY [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRENUMERO]
            HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRODUTO]) = 1
        ) loja ON loja.PRENUMERO = [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRENUMERO]
        WHERE [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRODUTO] > 1
     ) AS QtdeLoja,
     (SELECT COUNT([VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRENUMERO]) FROM [MXPETROL_AB].[dbo].[VendasPOS_Linhas] 
      INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRENUMERO]
            FROM
                [MXPETROL_AB].[dbo].[VendasPOS_Linhas]
            JOIN    [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos]
            ON    [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRENUMERO] = [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[PRENUMERO]
            WHERE
                [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[FACT_VD] like 'T' AND
                [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[DATA] > '2015-06-01 00:00:00.000' AND 
                [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[Armazem] = '454'
            GROUP BY [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRENUMERO]
            HAVING MIN([VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRODUTO]) = 1 AND MAX([VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRODUTO]) <> 1 AND COUNT(DISTINCT [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRODUTO]) > 
        ) mista ON mista.PRENUMERO = [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRENUMERO]
     ) AS QtdeMista
```

### Explicação

#### SELECT interno

```
            SELECT [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRENUMERO]
            FROM
                [MXPETROL_AB].[dbo].[VendasPOS_Linhas]
            JOIN    [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos]
            ON    [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRENUMERO] = [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[PRENUMERO]
            WHERE
                [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[FACT_VD] like 'T' AND
                [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[DATA] > '2015-06-01 00:00:00.000' AND 
                [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[Armazem] = '454'
            GROUP BY [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRENUMERO]
            HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRODUTO]) = 1
```

Devido ao `HAVING COUNT(...) = 1` só irá retornar `PRENUMERO` que tenham 1 único `PRODUTO` enquanto que no **último** `SELECT` eu faço `> 1` para pegar os `PRENUMERO` que são mistos

Após o retorno do `SELECT` mais de dentro, faço um `COUNT(...)` pra saber quantas `PRENUMERO` distintos me retornou.

Pra saber se é combustível ou loja eu faço na hora do `COUNT` mencionado anteriormente, se for combustível é `WHERE [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRODUTO] = 1` enquanto loja fica `WHERE [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRODUTO] > 1`. No caso da mista é indiferente.

Comment: Obrigado, tentei mas não deu. 
Apareceu QtddeCombustivel a 0, QtddeLoja a 3387 e QtdMista a 0

Comment: @Enato Eu coloquei o COUNT errado, estava passando `PRENUMERO` ao invés de `PRODUTO`, tenta novamente :)

Comment: Apareceu isto: http://i.imgur.com/xqZnbs7.png

Só que dá mais que o total, será que é porque o Combustivel e Loja estão a contar os mistos também?

Comment: @Enato como você está calculando o total?

Comment: assim:
   (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[PRENUMERO]) from VendasPOS_Linhas JOIN    [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos]
  ON    [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRENUMERO] = [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[PRENUMERO] where DATA> '2015-06-01 00:00:00.000' and Armazem = '454' AND [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[FACT_VD] like 'T') AS Total

Comment: Troca os meus `COUNT(1)` por `COUNT( DISTINCT [VendaPOS_Linhas]. [PRENUMERO])`

Comment: Ficou lá perto. O QtdComb ficou 1048. o de loja ficou a 1154 e o misto a 380 o que dá um total de 2582. Sobrou 75 :s

Comment: Estamos quaseeeeee

Comment: @Enato Faça um teste: 
SELECT [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRENUMERO], COUNT(DISTINCT [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRODUTO])
FROM
    [MXPETROL_AB].[dbo].[VendasPOS_Linhas]
JOIN    [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos]
ON    [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRENUMERO] = [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[PRENUMERO]
WHERE
    [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[FACT_VD] like 'T' AND
    [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[DATA] > '2015-06-01 00:00:00.000' AND 
    [VendasPOS_Cabecalhos].[Armazem] = '454'
GROUP BY [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRENUMERO]
ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRODUTO]) DESC

Comment: Verifica se tem prenumero com + de 2 no count

Comment: Sim, 75 Rows. vai do +3 ao +5

Comment: É normal? Erro meu no SQL então troca o último `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRODUTO]) = 2` por `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRODUTO]) > 1`

Comment: Atualizei a resposta com nossas alterações daqui

Comment: Resultou :D Mas a versão editada não funciona. Vou editar o meu com o resultado final certo para poder editar também. Poderia só dar uma explicação de como atingiu só para ver se fico a perceber melhor também?

Comment: @Enato Atualizei na resposta a explicação, se ficou confuso posso tentar explicar novamente. Se resolveu seu problema, fazendo favor marque a resposta como a solução.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Percebi direito

Comment: @Enato Alterei no meu também a sugestão que te falei abaixo, altere as partes que vc disse que não funcionava

Answer (score 1):

A pergunta já foi respondida mas, ainda assim, deixo uma resposta mais concisa e que evita as inúmeras sub-queries da solução original.

```
SELECT    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN MinProduto = 1 AND MaxProduto = 1 THEN PRENUMERO END) AS QtdCombustivel
         ,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN MinProduto <> 1 AND MaxProduto <> 1 THEN PRENUMERO END) AS QtdLoja
         ,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN MinProduto = 1 and MaxProduto <> 1 THEN PRENUMERO END) AS QtdMisto
         ,COUNT(DISTINCT PRENUMERO) AS TotalAbsoluto
FROM
(
    SELECT   VL.PRENUMERO
            ,COUNT(DISTINCT VL.PRODUTO) AS NumProduto
            ,MIN(VL.PRODUTO)            AS MinProduto
            ,MAX(VL.PRODUTO)            AS MaxProduto
    FROM    MXPETROL_AB.dbo.VendasPOS_Linhas VL
    INNER JOIN VendasPOS_Cabecalhos VC
       ON    VL.PRENUMERO = VC.PRENUMERO
    WHERE    VC.FACT_VD = 'T' 
      AND    VC.DATA > '2015-06-01 00:00:00.000' 
      AND    VC.Armazem = '454' 
    GROUP BY VL.PRENUMERO
) Res
```

Apenas alterei uma das tuas condições de

```
VC.FACT_VD LIKE 'T'
```

para

```
VC.FACT_VD = 'T'
```

visto que, como não estavas a utilizar wildcards, não se justificava a utilização do `LIKE`.

Edit:

Como solicitado nos comentários, esta query irá devolver os totais por dia:

```
SELECT    DATA
         ,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN MinProduto = 1 AND MaxProduto = 1 THEN PRENUMERO END) AS QtdCombustivel
         ,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN MinProduto <> 1 AND MaxProduto <> 1 THEN PRENUMERO END) AS QtdLoja
         ,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN MinProduto = 1 and MaxProduto <> 1 THEN PRENUMERO END) AS QtdMisto
         ,COUNT(DISTINCT PRENUMERO) AS TotalAbsoluto
FROM
(
    SELECT   VC.DATA 
            ,VL.PRENUMERO
            ,COUNT(DISTINCT VL.PRODUTO) AS NumProduto
            ,MIN(VL.PRODUTO)            AS MinProduto
            ,MAX(VL.PRODUTO)            AS MaxProduto
    FROM    MXPETROL_AB.dbo.VendasPOS_Linhas VL
    INNER JOIN VendasPOS_Cabecalhos VC
       ON    VL.PRENUMERO = VC.PRENUMERO
    WHERE    VC.FACT_VD = 'T' 
      AND    VC.DATA > '2015-06-01 00:00:00.000' 
      AND    VC.Armazem = '454' 
    GROUP BY VC.DATA, VL.PRENUMERO
) Res
GROUP BY DATA
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: Interessante o jeito que reduziu, acredito que funciona. @Enato testou?

Comment: Deu certo sim! Ficou mais pequeno assim também, além do reduzir isto não é tão pesado ou é igual ao outro código?

Comment: Só uma coisa, tanto neste código como no que marquei como solução ele está a contar estes como mistos não é? http://i.imgur.com/8CBFZvf.png
Naquele teste que fiz em cima que o @maicon-carraro pediu e deu alguns com +5, eu fui ver o prenumero desse e alguns tem só de loja ou só de combustivel

Comment: @Enato Experimente trocar o `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRODUTO]) > 1` no `SELECT` da qtdeMista do MEU SELECT por `HAVING MIN([VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRODUTO]) = 1 AND MAX([VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRODUTO]) <> 1 AND COUNT(DISTINCT [VendasPOS_Linhas].[PRODUTO]) > 1`

Comment: Deu bem menos resultados para o Misto (passou de 500 para 169) mas assim não dá o resultado final certo, deve faltar adicionar esses que tirou do misto ao da Loja. Penso que o problema é mesmo só o de Loja porque como o combustivel é sempre 1 ele conta bem. O produto de loja como é >1 mas há varios numeros diferentes ele não deve contar bem na loja. 
Há algo que se possa fazer no contarLoja? De qualquer das maneiras vou fazer as contas manualmente para ver se os resultados batem bem

Comment: @Enato, alterei a resposta de acordo com os teus comentários. Podes verificar se produz o resultado esperado?

Comment: Muito obrigado! Está perfeito agora. o <> significa diferente?

Comment: Sim, significa diferente. Ainda bem que funcionou.

Comment: Agora não sei se devo meter correcto este ou a outra, porque ambos funcionam.

Só mais uma coisa, se eu quiser ter mais uma column ao lado com as datas para cada dia é possível ?

Comment: Queres que, ao invés de apresentar apenas uma linha com o total, seja apresentada uma linha por cada data que tens na tabela?

Comment: EDIT: já consegui. Fiz assim: CONVERT(varchar,Data,101) AS Data